# What can be done to improve IE11 behaviour with Angular Material?

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-11, angular-material

I am working on a Angular project wherein I have used Angular Material components (mainly md-Buttons). The application shows various tiles each one of which is md-Button. At a time I will probably have 20-30 tiles max. These tiles are repeated using `ng-repeat`.

The application works good enough on Chrome, however on IE11, I am facing rendering issue regularly. Rendering takes around 5-6 seconds. Toggling tiles display works poorly. Scrolling screen leads to the components sticking and then moving after say 1 sec.

Probably I guess Angular Material is too heavy for IE11. Is there something I can do to speed up things on IE11 as this is my primary target browser?

I have tried:

1. Updating Angular libraries.
2. Using MS052 patch
3. Removing few transitions from Angular Material css.

None of the above seems to have much effect.

I think Angular material is a good library and there must be something that can be done to improve its working in IE11. Please can someone suggest something effective?

Answer (score 5):

We are also working on angular project and we are facing performance troubles with Internet Explorer 11.

I found this bug on github that helped me :
https://github.com/angular/material/issues/1771

Solution:
In the last version 0.11.1 they worked on layout display issues for Internet Explorer so I just updated to angular material to v0.11.1 and added this line to my angular config JavaScript file :

```
$provide.constant('$MD_THEME_CSS', '/**/');
```

The performance improved for Internet Explorer 11.

Answer (score 0):

I found that wrapping all of my js in IIFEs and adding "use strict;" everywhere that's appropriate improved the performance of my Angular Material app considerably. It's still slower than Chrome on IE, but the performance is not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with CSS.

Use clean-css NPM module to make IE compatible CSS
run below code in runkit.com and get IE optimize CSS
For More info see compatibility option of clean-css

https://runkit.com/npm/clean-css-pre-2.1.0

```
var request = require("request")
CleanCSS = require("clean-css-pre-2.1.0")

var url = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.1/angular-material.min.css"

request({
    url: url,
}, function (error, response, body) {

    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        var source = body;
        var minimized = new CleanCSS({compatibility : '*'}).minify(source);
        console.log(minimized)
    }
})
```